# Login prompt in spite of having windows authentication enabled

Tags: .net, iis, windows-authentication

We have enabled Windows authentication (Anonymous access is disabled) in IIS but, I am getting prompt to enter user-credentials for application
Checked for the providers under authentication and the order is correct as well.

Any pointers would be helpful.
For information is it a .NET application hosted on IIS 7.5

Comment: `Anonymous access is disabled` => `I am getting prompt to enter user-credentials` => what's the problem exactly or can we assume that's a typo?

Comment: We have enabled Windows authentication  in IIS but, I am still getting prompt to enter user-credentials for application         . I also checked for the providers under authentication and the order is correct as well.

Any pointers would be helpful, on what can be possible solution so, that prompt to enter credentials in not presented to user. For information is it a .NET application hosted on IIS 7.5

Comment: Validated all entries in application, web.config, they are correct. It used to work (this issue came up suddently few days back) i.e. prompt was not displayed and user would get logged in based on their window's credentials.

Comment: Have you checked [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517127/windows-authentication-not-working-in-iis-7-5)?

Comment: Yes, checked other aspects as well, still somehow it doesn't seem to work. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is old but i hope it may be helpful for someone like me in near future.

1. In Windows Authentication feature, goto providers. Just ensure that the NTLM is the only provider selected and remove the Negotiate. It would stop the logon prompt to show up.
2. Not sure if this may also be needed but, In advanced Settings, change the value to Off.

For anyone who uses this in a web api and trying to call that from another app, say, angular or anything, then the webapi in IIS also needs to have the Anonymous authentication enabled along with the Windows authentication.

[image]

[image]
Earlier, i had the NTLM and Negotiate as two providers, even though the NTLM was moved/kept at the top, it kept prompting for logon in all the browsers. After removing the Negotiate provider, it cooled off not to prompt anymore :)

[image]